# Call Directory Extension - no extension found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit

I have an app using the Call Directory Extension. I log analytics on all the errors my users receive from the extension and out of around 260 users receiving errors this month, 7 users received an error that the extension was not found.

I know that is a really small percentage of users, but I'm curious why anyone would ever not have the extension installed with my app.

Is it possible that sometimes there is just a corrupted app download that fails to install the extension along with the app? Or is there anything I can do on my end to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you double check the `Deployment Target` of app and extension.

Comment: @QuocNguyen just checked and the Deployment Target matches for app and extension. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an OS issue / installation error:

I had the same issue with an app that was distributed with an enterprise distribution certificate to >1000 Users. One single user reported the issue (we have an error message in the app). When checking his mobile phone, the Caller Identification / Blocking settings were indeed missing.

After deinstallation of our app and installation of a separate app with Caller Identification / Blocking from the App Store, the setting appeared. After that and re-installing our app the error was gone.